# Ubuntu 20.04 Nvidia Drivers Laptop Dual Graphics Not Installing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hybrid-graphics

**Edit** Due to the time sensitive nature of my issue (I needed the gpu asap) I ended up just installing arch (manjaro) and it was able to recognize and install Nvidia Prime drivers (440). However, Thanks for all the help.

I have searched and searched and cannot find any solutions to my specific problem. Basically, I have an Asus Zenbook UX303ub, which shipped with an i7 6th gen, and an Nvidia GT940m. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and I can't seem to get the Nvidia GPU to run. Here is what I have done so far

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices -> No output
```

I have tried using the Nvidia drivers [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/83686/en-us), which is the nvidia-346 version if I'm not mistaken. The installation fails with

```
ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for
       details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README
       available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I can't seem to find the log file at that path. But I don't think that is the issue, I have also tried

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install nvidia-346
```

As well as different versions (nvidia-349, etc). Regardless of what version, it throws this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nvidia-346 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'nvidia-346' has no installation candidate
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-346
```

When I try `lspci -v`  it shows that a Xeon E3 and Intel Skylake GT2 graphics, no mention of nvidia.

I'm really stumped, and I would appreciate any input.

output

```
 $ lspci -k | grep -iEA4 "VGA|3D|Display"

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
--
```

Comment: Why nvd-346 ? `apt search nvidia-driver-*` will show the available candidates. I do use the 435, the 440 didn't work with my external monitor.
Also, don't you have `nvidia-settings`  installed ? (maybe it comes with the driver, I don't remember).  What's the full output of `llspci -k | grep -iEA4 "VGA|3D|Display"`. Also (again), you may have some things to do to blacklist nouveau (that isnt as effective as the proprietary drivers...)

Comment: [Additional doc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

Comment: @B.duGaray Thanks for your reply. I listed the available candidates, it shows a few, like 440, 390. Here is the otput from lspci 

```
lspci -k | grep -iEA4 "VGA|3D|Display"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
```

Comment: I backlisted nouevuea and tried installing the nvidia 440 drivers from their site, and it gives me this: 

You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 440.100 NVIDIA   
           Linux graphics driver installed in this system.  For further details,     
           please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in the README     
           available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.   

I am certain that I have the GT940m in this laptop, so I'm not sure what the issue is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right. Your NVIDIA isn't recognized.
My solution was run fresh new Ubuntu install and mark **" Install Third Party Software".**

This way system choose a proper drivers and everything works.
Hope you too, as well.

Here is the easiest solution to be sure, you completely purge NVIDIA, repository, etc. After that, you don't neeed to install any other additional graphics driver. It will be the Intel Graphics.

[image]